# Finding an element over an extension over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ which reduced to the desired residue field element

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $f = x^4 - 2x^2 - 1/3 \in K[x]$.

Suppose that $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$. With Magma, I computed that the residue field of $L$ is given by $\mathbb{F}_4 = \mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is an element with minimal polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Further, I noticed that the reductions of all four roots of $f$ in $L$ are equal to $1$.

> **Question**: How can I find an element $\beta \in L$ such that the reduction of $\beta$ is $\alpha$, i.e. $\bar{\beta} = \alpha$?

Since the reductions of all four roots of $f$ in $L$ are equal to $1$, I probably need to combine these roots to obtain such a $\beta$ - now I am interested in how to do this in a systematic way. It would be nice if you have any advice for this kind of problem.

Comment: Since the roots are repeated one can't just use Hensel's lemma naively to lift a solution from the residue field to $L$ - you need to consider the solutions over the rings $\mathcal{O}_L/(\pi_L^i)$ for some larger values of $i$ and use the stronger form of Hensel's lemma

Comment: I think I misunderstand since this doesn't depend on the roots of $f$, but if you just want an element $\beta \in L$ that reduces down to $\alpha$, we can start at $\alpha$ and Teichmuller lift it from the residue field. In general if $f$ is the residue degree (not the same $f$ as our polynomial, just conventional notation), then repeatedly mapping $x \mapsto x^{p^f}$ will converge to it, in a limit that looks like $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha^{p^{fn}} = \beta$. So not only does this element reduce back down to $\alpha$, it even satisfies $\beta^{p^f-1}=1$ like it.

Comment: I would take as $\beta$ a root of the polynomial $x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb Q_2[x]$, no?

Comment: With this specific $f$ you can simply do the following. We have $$f=(x^2-1)^2-4/3,$$ so $\alpha_1^2=1+(2/\sqrt3)$ and $\alpha_2^2=1-(2/\sqrt3)$ describe two zeros, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$, of $f$, the other two being $-\alpha_1$ and $-\alpha_2$. Anyway, we see that
$$(\alpha_1\alpha_2)^2=-1/3.$$ Hence (with a bit of abuse of notation)
$$\omega=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2=(-1+\dfrac1{\alpha_1\alpha_2})/2$$
is a primitive third root of unity in $L$. This can serve in the role of $\beta$.